# Set button to disabled when AccessDataSource has no rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I am using an AccessDataSource control bound to a DetailsView control.  When the select returns no rows (the DetailsView disappears, but is still set to visible), then I would like to disable some further functionality by disabling a button.

In the C# code behind, I know I will need:

```
ButtonMyButton.enabled = false;
```

However, I am uncertain of a way of getting the information from the AccessDataSource or the DetailsView that would let me know when to set the value.

I have seen some other articles that suggested the example of for a similar item:

```
        DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        int reorderedProducts = (int)dv.Table.Rows[0][0]
```

For me, DataView is in error as not having the right namespace, despite having:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

What should I do to disable the button?

(While this is a real newbie question, it is not school homework, since that seems to be the first comment on so many simple questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AccessDataSource` inherits from the `SqlDataSource` class. It therefore provides an event called [`Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selected.aspx) which is the event raised after the SELECT operation is completed. This event should have an EventArgs parameter of the type [`SqlDataSourceEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.aspx)).

This EventArgs parameter has a property called [`AffectedRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.affectedrows.aspx) which will tell you the count of rows retrieved. If it is 0, you can set the enabled property of your Button.

```
private void OnSelectedHandler(Object source, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
    //Disable the button.
}
```

For the record, the `DataView` class resides in the `System.Data` namespace. In addition, calling `Select()` on the AccessDataSource will mean that you are running two select statements, one to retrieve the records (if any), and the other simply to count the number of retrieved records.

Comment: This works perfectly for me.  Thank you for taking the time to explain.  I did have to change "private" to "protected" to work on my aspx.cs page.